# Caching in C++ (for beginners more or less)

Tags: c++, performance, caching, optimization, hash

So I'm not that new to C++ but the whole concept of peformance optimization and caching is. I implemented an Extendible Hashing Class in C++ (for school) and now I have to optimize it here and there.

Can someone explain to me in simple terms what caching is (and how it can be implemented in C++)...I found a few tutorials but I understood close to nothing. I read something about static variables that memorize and save in the Cache memory the last thing some method calculated and return it. The funtion only recalculates when the initial parameters change (sorry if I didn't explain that too good :D).

From what I understood so far about caching I tought that (for the min and max methods from my ExtHash Class, for example) I can somehow cache the min and max values in variables and then every time I add or remove an element in the table I'll only have to compare that element to the cached min or max to determine if the min and max have to change (I don't need to go through the entire array again to find the new min and max).
Did I understand correctly? How can that be done?

I would really appreciate it if someone took his time to explain that a little bit.

Comment: Related search term:  'memoize'

Comment: Caching is statically (taking shortcuts) - unless you have measurements, analysis (or a good guess) of the program behavior, avoid it.,

Comment: well I have a few charts (performace test)...and I know I have to optimize a few functions (add, min, max) in order to get some points...

Answer (score 2):

Let's say it. Caching is you temporarily store something you might need in future.

I would give you an example. Here your function foo have some functionality of computing (what ever it is).

While the function foo() can be an expensive computing function.

Your client code side might have:

```
int a = foo(10);
int b = foo(11);
int c = foo(11);
```

In case of you don't know the c is the same as b, you will calculate by 'foo' which can be expensive.

Now Let's change this into caching:

```
int bar(int key)
{
    static int s_key = key;
    static int s_value = foo(key);
    if ( key == s_key ) return s_value;

    s_key   = key;
    s_value = foo(key);
    return s_value;
}
```

Now you don't have to duplicate the computing on `foo(11)`.

But, this is only an one-entry cache, can only handle when you calculate easy duplicated input.

If you are handling an n-entry caching, you need some other algorithm to manage the caching, e.g "LRU"

Comment: @Poc-pităcuunsoare Just use 4 indents before each line

Comment: This code will fail when first called with `bar(0)` and `foo(0)` isn't also zero by change. You should rather initialize `s_key` and `s_value`, too. Like `static int s_key = key;` and `static int s_value = foo(key)`. This only runs the first time `bar` is called, so there's no performance hit...

Comment: @elmarZander, you're right. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The term *caching* can be thought of as storing a frequently used value or variable into a location that can be accessed quickly.

Disk drives *cache* data for frequently accessed sectors to help speed up access.  If the sector data has not changed, access time will be faster from memory than having to read from the platters.

Many processors have `Cache Memory`, which is located very close to the processor.  The *Data Cache* would be used to store frequently accessed data; so instead of accessing memory that is far away (RAM), the processor access the data in the cache that it already fetched.  The Cache Memory is designed to be very fast access.

A program can implement *caching* in various methods, depends on the operations and data.  Read a lot of data from the hard drive into a buffer is a form of caching.  Organizing matrices and other structures to fit into a line of *Cache Memory* is another form of Cache optimization.

Comment: Yes, ok...thanks, but I already read that in multiple places (I know what Cache memory is and I read some theory)...I asked for an example or some explanations to caching in C++. 

I have a method that returns the max in the hash-table. How can I cache that max in order to read it from the cache the next time a new element is added into the table (so that the program doesn't need to calculate the max again...it just has to compare the newest added element to the cached max and if needed to update the max).

Answer (score 0):

When you talk of caching in terms of your program, this is usually done to store data where transaction time is large i.e. processes which take some time to get data (the reason you are caching stuff). Some common examples are data reads from databases, files on the disk etc. What usually I have come across in these cases is that a data structure is used in c++ like vectors, maps or lists etc. Also another thing that I have observed is that caching is done for more or less static data (which does not change on the fly; if you cache dynamic data, it is stupid) . Type of these structures depends on the type data you want to store.So e.g. you have some ref. Data stored in a database and you want to cache that data in your program space.

```
class MyCacheExample
{
public:
    // cctor and destructor
    MyCacheExample(void);
    ~MyCacheExample(void);

    // Caching structures
    std::vector<CString> firstNameVec;
    std::vector<CString>::iterator itr;

    void CacheSomeData()
    {
        // Setup DB related stuff which is required to create session and connect to a DB
        CDatabase dbConn;
        CRecordset rcrdSet(&dbConn);
        CString sDbConnString = L"ODBC;DSN=FOO;UID=abcd;PWD=efgh";

        // query to be fired on the data (in this case the data we want to cache as DB transactions are any day slower than local memory lookup)
        CString sQry = L"select first_name from name_table";

        // Open the DB connection and fire the query
        dbConn.OpenEx(sDbConnString,CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
        // fire the query and get the result in the CRecordset object
        rcrdSet.Open(CRecordset::snapshot,sQry);

        // Setup the iterator to start caching your data
        itr = firstNameVec.begin();

        // Get data from the result set stored in rcrdSet object
        while(!rcrdSet.IsEOF())
        {
            CString tmp;
            rcrdSet.GetFieldValue(short(1),tmp);
            // insert the data into the vector i.e. "cache" the data for quick look up
            firstNameVec.insert(itr,tmp);
            rcrdSet.MoveNext();
            it++;
        }
        rcrdSet.Close();
        dbConn.Close();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyCacheExample ex;
    ex.CacheSomeData();
    /* your logic code here about what you want to do with the cached data */
}
```

ignore the DB stuff (it is MFC based DB connection and data fetch if you were wondering). "Caching" here happens inside the while loop. Suppose there was a table called as user_details and has fields like first_name , last_name , age etc.. I am caching the first name of ALL the people from this table. Now after the while loop completes, I don t have to look up the DB every time I want a first name rather I can use the data cached in a local structure (here a vector).
Type of structure used is based on the logic you want and the nature of cached data e.g. maps and sets are used for key val pair based data.
If you want to compare the two reads I.e. cache and DB the latter takes about a few seconds to about some minutes depending on the size of data. But the former takes barely a few microseconds.

NOTE that caching is a term and in this case has nothing to do with the computer (processor) cache memory. Infact this data that you are "caching" will be fetched in the program memory i.e. RAM. One more thing that you never fetch large amounts of cache data. Obvious reasons being you will fall short of RAM (user information in a system where 1 million+ users exist; such data runs into GBs). Second your program space will bloat up and hence your program is no longer "light".

Similarly you can read data from data sources where reading can cost you time and effect system performance e.g. files on a disk (use fstream and string/ stringstream)
Also making something static does not mean that you cache data. static is a way to define the scope of data i.e. whether it is object level or class level.
Cached data may or may not be static and depends on the nature of the data and the logic one is using and whether the data is required post an object's de referencing.
And yes you might need some caching policy too e.g. LRU LFU FIFO and many more ( you could use this when you want to cache dynamic data for future reference and when the data set is large and some cached values have to be removed to make space for a new one)
Hope this answers your question(s)?